# Trouble in shadow caustics

Tags: lighting, caustics

[image]

When transmitting light using the ocean plane, the shadow of the object is displayed as in the right image. I was hoping that the shadow would be formed according to the normal map of the seaweed as in the left image. What kind of problem is this?

I applied "Cast Shadow", a new feature of Blender version 3.2, to the ocean plane and "Receive Shadow" to the white background layer.

[Here is the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vT-30uyo10yCkwAEEyICjuw7Iiz7OqXm/view)

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?

Comment: In addition to providing a file you should also describe all the relevant context as well. There is also a difference between shadow caustics and caustics shadow.

Comment: Agreed with @MartynasŽiemys .. please show us the settings you have made that you think should be achieving the desired result.

Comment: @moonboots https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vT-30uyo10yCkwAEEyICjuw7Iiz7OqXm/view?usp=drive_link Here is my file link! thanks

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys
It's my first question, so I don't have enough explanation, sorry. I applied 'cast shadow', a new feature added to version 3.2 blender, to the ocean plane and 'receive shadow' to the white background plane. I'd appreciate if you refer to the link file above.